# From 2 disks RAID 0 to 2 disks RAID 1 without data loss?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, dell-poweredge

I'm trying to change the RAID configuration on my Dell Poweredge server from RAID 0 to RAID 1.

I have two drives installed, each 300GB, both in 1 virtual drive configured as RAID 0. As the data on those drives is pretty sensitive, I would like to make sure that I still have it when one of both drives would fail.

My question: is there a way to convert the RAID configuration on that drives to RAID 1 without data loss? If so,how? If not, what are my best options to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Backup your data. Reconfigure the array. Restore your data.

Comment: Also note: A RAID is in no way a replacement for a backup. Ever.

Comment: 1) If your data is sensitive then you already have at least one well tested backup, so you could just wipe and restore. 
2) No. RAID0 needs both drives. That leaves none to convert to RAID1.

Answer (score 4):

> is there a way to convert the RAID configuration on that drives to
>   RAID 1 without data loss?

No.